# Using Power Pivot when Columns are Dates

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a very large data set that has 15,000 rows with a few descriptive columns and then the data itself is stored as monthly sales in 200 columns, one for each month. There are a couple of other data sets I need to connect this to so I want to be able to use Power Pivot to build the relationships.

How do I go about harnessing Power Pivot to build a dashboard for this data? Specifically is there a way to link all those date columns to a DimDate table so I can connect it to other data sets without reformatting the whole data set?

Comment: Your first question cannot be answered before you tell us what kind of dashboard you are going to build. You can create relationship between months and a DimDate table but you will have to unpivot your dataset. Check [this example](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) where a table with date columns is unpivoted.

Comment: Thanks so much this is exactly what I was trying to figure out. If there was  a way to to use this data without unpivoting it. I know with power query it is a relatively straight forward exercise but I didn't want to have to create a duplicate set of the data in my workbook just to store it unpivoted.

Comment: There is no way to relate this data with the DimDate table without unpivot it. PowerQuery loads data to your PowerPivot model from several sources (included Excel workbooks), you won't have repeated data in your model at least if don't do so.